# I have posted so many questions, but no answers to them

Tags: discussion, profile-page, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I have posted so many questions, but I didn't get any answers to them, and by any chance they have been deleted or rejected. Where can I see them on Stack Overflow?

I didn't see them anywhere when I logged in.

Comment: You have no deleted questions. Your questions are listed here https://stackoverflow.com/users/9729432/kriss?tab=questions

Answer (score 1):

You can view your own 'deleted' questions & answers in your Profile > Activity > Questions or Answers ('View More') > click on 'recently deleted Q or A'

[image]

> This page shows answers you posted that were deleted in the last 60 days. This includes answers to questions that were deleted.